# VC++: Performance drop x20 when more threads than cpus but not under g++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Simple multithreaded c++11 program where all threads lock same mutex in tight loop.

When it uses 8 threads (as the number of logical cpus) it can reach 5 million locks/second

But add just one additional thread - and the performance drops To 200,000/sec !

**Edit:**

**Under g++4.8.2 (ubuntu x64): No performance degradation at all even with 100 threads!** (and more than twice the performance but that's another story)
 - **So this indeed seems to be a problem specific to VC++ mutex implementation**

I reproduced it with the following code (Windows 7 x64):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

void thread_loop(std::mutex* mutex, std::atomic_uint64_t* counter)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(*mutex);        
        counter->operator++();                    
    }        
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    

    int threads = 9;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::atomic_uint64_t counter = 0;

    std::cout << "Starting " << threads << " threads.." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        new std::thread(&thread_loop, &mutex, &counter);

    std::cout << "Started " << threads << " threads.." << std::endl;
    while (1)
    {   
        counter = 0;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));        
        std::cout << "Counter = " << counter.load() << std::endl;                
    }    
}
```

The VS 2013 profiler tells me that most of time (95.7%) is wasted in a tight loop (line 697 in rtlocks.cpp):

```
while (IsBlocked() & & spinWait._SpinOnce())
{
//_YieldProcessor is called inside _SpinOnce
}
```

What could be the cause? How can this be improved?

OS: windows 7 x64

CPU: i7 3770 4 cores (x2 hyper threading)

Comment: Why does that surprise you? A contending mutex is costly!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sure, but sudden drop in scaling efficiency is interesting...

Comment: anyway OP should try g++, you have simple 7zip for win dl on isocpp

Comment: @molbdnilo doh, you are right

Comment: It's not very interesting at all, it's expected. A mutex will usually spin a few times before blocking. Spinning with threads > cpus is death.

Comment: Yeah - your thread code is 99.99% system calls with a trivial counter increment added in. Sure enough, 99.99% of the time is spent in the system calls.

Answer (score 8):

With 8 threads your code is spinning, but getting the lock without the CPU having to suspend the thread before it looses its time slice.

As you add more and more threads the contention level increases, and therefore the chance that the thread will not be able to acquire the lock within its timeslice. When this happens the thread is suspended and a context swith occurs to another thread, which the CPU will examine to see if the thread can be woken up.

All this swithing, suspending and waking up requires a transition from user mode to kernel mode, and this is an expensive operation, thus performace is significantly impacted.

To improve things either reduce the number of threads contending the lock or increase the number of cores available. In your example you're using a `std::atomic` number, so you don't need to lock in order to call `++` on it, since it's already thread safe.

Comment: Performance lose due to context switching is expected. The problem it is a very severe loss of performacne. From 5 million/sec to 200,000

Comment: @GabiMe: What do you think happens while a process holds a lock an another one is scheduled and starts spinning? While the scheduled process is trying to acquire the lock, the condition the spinning thread waits for cannot possibly become true. That's why spinning with more threads than there are cores is death.

Comment: What @Damon says.  Spinlocks perform badly when the number of ready threads is greater than the number of cores, and extremely badly when the proportion of 'useful work' to inter-thread synchro overhead is very small, as in OP case.  CPU cycles and memory-bandwith are essentially being pissed away on attempts to acquire locks that are held by threads that are ready, but not running.  Performance will improve if the spinlock-count of the mutex is set to zero, so allowing immediate blocking if a thread cannot get the lock.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to try and set the spinlock count to zero?

Comment: Not sure about C++11 mutex, but you can do it with a critical section object - a mutex that is restricted to threads within a single process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The mutex gives contention between each of the threads anyway, however if you try to use more threads than you have cores, even if they are ready, not all of them can run at once, so they will need to keep stopping and starting - known as context switching.

The only way you can "solve" this is to use fewer threads or get more cores.

Comment: According to the profiler the problem isnt in the kernel context switching..It is specifically in the spinlock code of the c++ runtime

Comment: @GabiMe - yes, as would be expected when the thread code spends nearly all its time in inter-thread comms kernel API calls.  The counter increment is almost an irrelevance.

Comment: 'if you try to use more READY threads than you have cores'.  This answer is misleading/incorrect in assigning this effect to context-switch overhead instead of inefficient use of a locking scheme but, as is common in 'multithreading', it has accumulated the highest votes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there are 8 threads **store** to a shared resource (not **load**, load a shared resource which can't modified is safe, and lock is needless).

1. **8 threads > core num** means

   - not every thread can run in a single cpu
   - there are more task schedules
2. **mutex**

   - the thread can't acquired the mutext will sleep, and queued this thread to wait queue.(It seems the mutex implementation in windows use a short spin, then queued this thread to wait queue if not acquired the mutex?)

Write lock-free algorithm is hard, but in your problem, there is a way.

1. If you can get more cores, get them
2. use `std::atomic<uint64_t>` and delete the mutex, increase an atomic number is atomic by default(no special memory model).
3. If the thread num is not constant, then change it to the core num, and then bind them

---

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

void thread_loop(std::atomic<uint64_t>* counter)
{
    while (true)
    {
            (*counter)++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int threads = 9;
    std::atomic<uint64_t> counter(0);

    std::cout << "Starting " << threads << " threads.." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        new std::thread(&thread_loop, &counter);

    std::cout << "Started " << threads << " threads.." << std::endl;
    while (1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
        std::cout << "Counter = " << counter.load() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This maybe faster. enjoy ;-)

Comment: `increase an atomic number is atomic by default`, not if you mean read-modify-write

Comment: @Leeor I mean memory model, the default memory model in atomic template is [std::memory_order_seq_cst](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), it's safe. We also can use `std::memory_order_acquire` and `std::memory_order_release` to get the `acquires-release` semantics.

Comment: seq_cst doesn't prevent another thread from storing to the shared location between you read its value and store it back incremented.

Comment: @Leeor Yes, load the value then store it is not atomic, but `compare_exchange_xxxx` is born for it.